# datepicker обернуть в функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Кто то знает почему из функции не могу вызвать air datepicker?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.add-tarif__period-date').on('click', function(e){
        var start = $(this).find('.startDate').attr("id");
        var end = $(this).find('.endDate').attr("id");
        startCalendar(start, end);
    });
    


    function startCalendar(start, end) {
        var disabledTarifDates = [];

        var $starttarifDate = start;
        var $endtarifDate = end;

        $starttarifDate.datepicker({
            inline: false,
            range: true,
            toggleSelected: true,
            minDate: new Date(),
            multipleDatesSeparator: ",",
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            onSelect: function (fd, date) {
                if(date){
                    var arrDate = fd.split(",");
                    $starttarifDate.val(arrDate[0]);
                    $endtarifDate.val(arrDate[1]);
                    if(arrDate[1]){
                        $('.datepicker').css("left", "-100000px");
                        $starttarifDate.blur();
                    }
                    $endtarifDate.on('click', function () {
                        $starttarifDate.datepicker().val(arrDate[0]).data('datepicker').show();
                    });

                    disabledDates.forEach(function () {
                        console.log(321);
                        console.log(disabledTarifDates[0]);
                        console.log($starttarifDate.val());
                        console.log($endtarifDate.val());

                        if(new Date($starttarifDate.val()) < new Date('24-05-2018') && new Date($endtarifDate.val()) > new Date('24-05-2018')){
                            console.log(123);
                        }
                    })

                }
            },
            onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
                var formatted = getFormattedDate(date);
                if (cellType == 'day') {
                    var returnDay = {
                        disabled: false
                    };
                    var selectedDate = disabledDates.filter(function(date){
                        return date == formatted;
                    }).length;
                    if( selectedDate > 0 ){
                        returnDay = {
                            classes: 'add-to-disable-day',
                            disabled: true
                        };
                    }
                    return returnDay;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function getFormattedDate(date) {
        var year = date.getFullYear(),
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,
            date = date.getDate();
        return year + '-' + month + '-' + date;
    }
    
});
```

```css
.add-tarif__period-date{
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: spase-around;
  margin: 30px;
}
.add-tarif__period-date input {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="add-tarif__period-date">
    <div>
        <input class="startDate" type="text" readonly="" id="startOne">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="endDate" type="text" readonly="" id="endOne">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="add-tarif__period-date">
    <div>
        <input class="startDate" type="text" readonly="" id="startTwo">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="endDate" type="text" readonly="" id="endTwo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы передаёте в функцию `id` элементов. Т.е. строки. К строкам `datepicker` применить не получится. Передавайте элементы (т.е. убирайте в получении параметров `attr("id")`, или получайте эти элементы внутри функции по `id`.
2. Массив у Вас `disabledTarifDates`, а обращаетесь Вы везде к disabledDates.

Пример кода: https://jsfiddle.net/0uxL39rd/6/

Comment: C 1 я согласен, затупил. 
Но проблема остается той же, я не могу инициализировать `datepicker` из функции

Comment: а какая у Вас ошибка возникает?

Comment: проблема была в том, что я инициализировал `datepicker` по клику, а нужно сразу при формировании `DOM`. Помогла функция `each()`